# Tools for generating texture atlases/sprites from source images?

Tags: iphone, textures, objective-c, sprites

Is there an industry standard file format for texture atlases?

What are the apps that take a directory of images and turns it into a texture atlas png and a text file describing what's on it?

This is primarily for use in OpenGL iPhone/Objective-C, but it seems like there ought to be a standard across many platforms.  I can create these by hand or by writing a script to simply tile them, but it seems like there would be some tools already made for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Zwoptex](http://www.zwoptexapp.com/). I think it would do exactly what you want for your iPhone game. And if you have not tried [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) yet, Zwoptex is supported by it.

Comment: Thanks, Zwoptex looks great!  I'm not into cocos2d, but it should still integrate pretty easily.

Answer (score 3):

[SpriteSheetPacker](https://github.com/nickgravelyn/SpriteSheetPacker) is an extendible tile sheet packer. It can export sheet look up tables in a text format and in XML by default, but you can write plug ins in C# to add new export formats.

Comment: Thanks, that looks decent, although something running on OS X would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Texture Packer](http://www.texturepacker.com/) to create sprites for my iPhone game. It's similar to Zwoptex but is multi-platform and has a free version.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) myself  it is a commandline tool, but quite good, because it can do craploads of things (even converting between file formats, doing minor edits, some optmizations...)  and because it is commandline you can make scripts to use it in the most awesomenest way possible...

I made a script geared for my pipeline, that consisted of calling it from a folder full of animations, and the sprite sheet would "pop" out already optmized and in .png, does not matter what was the input frames :)

Comment: Thanks, speeder.  ImageMagick is actually what I have been using, but it only seems to be able to export a clean grid of images, which isn't as dense as it could be.  I agree, though, that the scriptability aspect is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Shoebox, perfect tool and it's free!

http://www.renderhjs.net/shoebox/
Works for most platforms too!